An internal error occurred during: "Check Configuration". loader constraint violation: when resolving method 'org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory
I have installed the cucumber plugin and after that whenever I am launching Eclipse IDE it is not responding. Getting the below error:

An internal error occurred during: "Check Configuration".
loader constraint violation: when resolving method 'org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()' the class loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @2dc704aa of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @56a0be17 for the method's defining class, org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder, have different Class objects for the type org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory used in the signature (org.slf4j.LoggerFactory is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @2dc704aa, parent loader 'platform';
org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder is in unnamed module of loader org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader @56a0be17, parent loader 'platform')

In addition to the above getting another error as well:

An internal error occurred during: "Git Repository Change Scanner".
org/eclipse/egit/core/RepositoryCache

How can I solve this?
Tried with
multiple time restarting the IDE
installed the latest version of cucumber plugin and junit and all other dependencies.

Which version of Eclipse are you using? What version of the Cucumber plug-in (an actual version number)?

Kindy help me and provide me the solution ASAP. I am stuck. Please help.

@nitind The eclipse version is 2024-03 and the cucumber version is 1.0.0.202106240526. Please help me soon sir. I am stuck.
